404 - /src/controller/registrar_venta.php - No such file or directory | 200 - POST /src/controller/registrar_venta.php
Cuando ejecuto el programa me menciona que el archivo no existe en la dirección a pesar de que esta presente, ya verifique tanto el nombre del archivo como de la carpeta e incluso a volví a eliminar y renombrar
Me ejecuta estos mensaje que dice
[Mon Jun 10 10:18:44 2024] [404] /src/controller/registrar_venta.php - No such file or directory  
[Mon Jun 10 03:18:44 2024] [::1]:56331 [200]: POST /src/controller/registrar_venta.php

Si alguien porfavor me pudiera mencionar cual es el inconveniente o que deberia ajustar me serviria de mucha ayuda
'ventas.js'
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const searchBtn = document.getElementById("searchBtn");
    const searchInput = document.getElementById("buscarProducto");
    const searchResults = document.getElementById("result-body");

    searchBtn.addEventListener("click", buscarProducto);
    searchInput.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
        if (e.key === "Enter") {
            buscarProducto();
        }
    });

    function buscarProducto() {
        const query = searchInput.value.trim();
        if (query === "") {
            searchResults.innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }

        fetch(`../controller/buscar_producto_ventas.php?q=${encodeURIComponent(query)}`)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                searchResults.innerHTML = data;
                attachAddToCartEventListeners();
            })
            .catch(error => console.error("Error al buscar productos:", error));
    }

    function attachAddToCartEventListeners() {
        document.querySelectorAll(".add-to-cart").forEach((button) => {
            button.addEventListener("click", function () {
                const id = this.dataset.id;
                const nombre = this.dataset.nombre;
                const precio = parseFloat(this.dataset.precio);
                const cantidad = 1;
                const imagen = this.dataset.imagen;

                const existingProductIndex = carrito.findIndex(producto => producto.id === id);
                if (existingProductIndex !== -1) {
                    carrito[existingProductIndex].cantidad++;
                } else {
                    const producto = { id, nombre, precio, cantidad, imagen };
                    carrito.push(producto);
                }
                
                renderCart();
            });
        });
    }

    let carrito = [];

    function renderCart() {
        const cartContainer = document.getElementById("cart-items");
        cartContainer.innerHTML = carrito.map(producto => `
            <tr>
                <td>${producto.nombre}</td>
                <td>${producto.precio.toFixed(2)}</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="cantidad">${producto.cantidad}</span>
                </td>
                <td><button class="remove-from-cart" data-id="${producto.id}">Eliminar</button></td>
                <td><img src="${producto.imagen}" alt="${producto.nombre}" width="50"></td>
            </tr>
        `).join("");

        document.querySelectorAll(".remove-from-cart").forEach((button) => {
            button.addEventListener("click", function () {
                const id = this.dataset.id;
                carrito = carrito.filter((producto) => producto.id !== id);
                renderCart();
            });
        });

        const total = carrito.reduce((sum, producto) => sum + (producto.precio * producto.cantidad), 0);
        document.getElementById("total-venta").innerText = total.toFixed(2);
    }

    document.getElementById("confirmar-venta").addEventListener("click", confirmarVenta);
    document.getElementById("cancelar-venta").addEventListener("click", cancelarVenta);

    function confirmarVenta() {
        const nombreCliente = document.getElementById("nombre").value.trim();
        const correoCliente = document.getElementById("correo").value.trim();
        const direccionCliente = document.getElementById("direccion").value.trim();
        const telefonoCliente = document.getElementById("telefono").value.trim();
        const metodoPagoSeleccionado = document.querySelector('input[name="metodoPago"]:checked');

        if (nombreCliente === "" || correoCliente === "" || direccionCliente === "" || telefonoCliente === "") {
            alert("Debes rellenar todos los datos del cliente");
            return;
        }
      
        if (carrito.length === 0) {
            alert("El carrito está vacío");
            return;
        }

        if (!metodoPagoSeleccionado) {
            document.getElementById("mensaje-pago").style.display = "block";
            return;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("mensaje-pago").style.display = "none";
        }

        const venta = {
            cliente: {
                nombre: nombreCliente,
                correo: correoCliente,
                direccion: direccionCliente,
                telefono: telefonoCliente
            },
            metodoPago: metodoPagoSeleccionado.value,
            carrito: carrito,
            total: parseFloat(document.getElementById("total-venta").innerText)
        };

        fetch("../controller/registrar_venta.php", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(venta)
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.status === "success") {
                alert("La venta se ha realizado de manera exitosa");
                carrito = [];
                renderCart();
                document.getElementById("form-cliente").reset();
                document.getElementById("form-pago").reset();
                window.location.href = `factura.php?ventaId=${data.ventaId}&clienteId=${data.clienteId}`;
            } else {
                alert("Error al confirmar la venta");
            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.error("Error al confirmar la venta:", error));
    }

    function cancelarVenta() {
        document.getElementById("form-cliente").reset();
        document.getElementById("form-pago").reset();
        carrito = [];
        renderCart();
    }
});

'registrar_venta.php'
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$conexion = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'libreriab');

if ($conexion->connect_error) {
    die(json_encode(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Conexión fallida a la base de datos']));
}

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
if (!$data) {
    echo json_encode(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Datos de entrada no válidos']);
    exit;
}

$cliente = $data['cliente'];
$metodoPago = $data['metodoPago'];
$carrito = $data['carrito'];
$total = $data['total'];

$fecharegistro = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$created_at = $fecharegistro;
$updated_at = $fecharegistro;

$ventaId = null;
$clienteId = null;

// Iniciar transacción
$conexion->begin_transaction();

try {
    // Insertar cliente
    $insertCliente = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO clientes (nombre_completo, correo_electronico, direccion, telefono, fecha_registro, creado_en, actualizado_en) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $insertCliente->bind_param("sssssss", $cliente['nombre'], $cliente['correo'], $cliente['direccion'], $cliente['telefono'], $fecharegistro, $created_at, $updated_at);

    if ($insertCliente->execute()) {
        $clienteId = $insertCliente->insert_id;

        // Verificar y actualizar stock de productos
        foreach ($carrito as $producto) {
            $productoId = $producto['id'];
            $cantidad = $producto['cantidad'];

            $selectProducto = $conexion->prepare("SELECT stock FROM productos WHERE id = ?");
            $selectProducto->bind_param("i", $productoId);
            $selectProducto->execute();
            $selectProducto->store_result();

            if ($selectProducto->num_rows > 0) {
                $selectProducto->bind_result($stock);
                $selectProducto->fetch();

                if ($stock >= $cantidad) {
                    $updateProducto = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE productos SET stock = stock - ? WHERE id = ?");
                    $updateProducto->bind_param("ii", $cantidad, $productoId);
                    $updateProducto->execute();
                } else {
                    throw new Exception("No hay suficiente stock para el producto con ID $productoId");
                }
            } else {
                throw new Exception("El producto con ID $productoId no existe");
            }
        }

        // Insertar venta
        $usuarioid = 1; // Reemplaza con el ID del usuario correspondiente
        $fechaventa = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $insertVenta = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO ventas_detalle (usuario_id, fecha_venta, total_venta, creado_en, actualizado_en) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $insertVenta->bind_param("isdss", $usuarioid, $fechaventa, $total, $created_at, $updated_at);

        if ($insertVenta->execute()) {
            $ventaId = $insertVenta->insert_id;

            // Confirmar la transacción
            $conexion->commit();

            echo json_encode(['status' => 'success', 'ventaId' => $ventaId, 'clienteId' => $clienteId]);
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Error al registrar la venta");
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Error al registrar el cliente");
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Rollback en caso de error
    $conexion->rollback();

    echo json_encode(['status' => 'error', 'message' => $e->getMessage()]);
}

$conexion->close();
?>



¿qué pasa si navegas directamente a tusitio.com/src/controller/registrar_venta.php?

me sale este resultado
{
"status": "error",
"message": "Datos de entrada no válidos"
}
estuve intentando chequear si tiene algo que ver con la base de datos, aunque no se si ese sea el inconveniente ya que contiene todas las columnas de las 3 tablas en donde debería actualizar la base de datos

Si tienes un error 404, no hay nada del script que llegue a ejecutarse. Ese error se produce cuando el web-server (por ejemplo apache) no encuentra el archivo que contiene el script. Sospecho que puede ser un problema de direcciones. Comenta aquí a qué dirección navegaste cuando te lo pedí, y en qué dirección está la página que invoca a ventas.js.

la dirección que ejecute fue por http://localhost:3000/src/controller/registrar_venta.php
mientras que la pagina que ejecuta ventas.js es de un archivo llamado 'ventas.php'
http://localhost:3000/src/views/Ventas.php
y el problema surge a la hora de que quiero que los datos se actualicen en la base de datos al presionar el botón de confirmar.

Intenta cambiar el fetch por la dirección absoluta, que sería: fetch("/src/controller/registrar_venta.php", . ¿Sigue sin funcionar?

cambie la dirección, más aun asi me sigue apareciendo el error
[Mon Jun 10 18:06:26 2024] [404] /src/controller/registrar_venta.php - No such file or directory
[Mon Jun 10 11:06:26 2024] [::1]:51436 [200]: POST /src/controller/registrar_venta.php
por lo que no ejecuta el registro
